# When dark energy became significant 6 billion years after the Big Bang was there anything else of significance going on in the universe?

Tags: supernova, dark-energy, galactic-evolution

I read that a lot of supernovas appeared at this time but were other major events or phenomenon occurring? I ask this in case there could be some physical process helping dark energy to strengthen or perhaps being helped by dark energy 6 billion years after the Big Bang

Answer (score 1):

The dark energy density doesn't strengthen. In the simplest model it stays exactly constant. What changes is the density of normal and dark matter, both of which decrease as the universe expands.

5 billion years ago, corresponding to a redshift of about 0.5, is just the time at which the energy densities of matter and dark energy were similar

Comment: When their energy densities were similar did that mean space was expanding at a constant rate.